# How to keep alive tcp socket in tcl

Tags: sockets, tcp, tcl, keep-alive

I have an issue,there is a piece of code which is in tcl opens a client socket in Linux. Because of my tests the socket is connection timed out after 2 hours. I'm looking for commands in tcl to keep alive the opened socket. So far I have got setsockopt,SO_KEEPALIVE all of these are in C language. Can someone help me how do we keep alive sockets in tcl.

I tried with setsockopt but it didn't worked as it is in C.I looked at tcp_keepalive_time,tcp_keepalive_intrvl,tcp_keepalive_probes which are in order 7200,75,9. I tried to modify those parameters but I dont have user permissions(admin restrictions).

```
if [catch {socket $use_host $use_port} comIdW] {  
   error "Error: Unable to connect to host $use_host port $use_port: $comIdW"
}
fconfigure $comIdW -buffering none -translation binary
set comIdR $comIdW
# I added following code based on my understanding
set optval 1
set optlen [llength $optval]
seetsockopt($comIdW,SOL_SOCKET,SO_KEEPALIVE,$optval,$optlen)
puts "SO_KEEPALIVE is ($optval ? "ON" : "OFF"))"
```

I wanted to keep this channel alive, it might be good If I can ping after 30 minutes of channel open

Comment: If the peer is closing the connection there is nothing you can do. TCP keepalive, despite its name, doesn't keep connections alive: it detects broken ones sooner.

Comment: So you mean, there is nothing we can do unless modify those system parameters i.e. tcp_keepalive_time,interval and probes to keep connection alive and is there any command like keepalive equivalent in TCL ?

Comment: Is there some sort of thing that you can send to the other end that it will respond with but which doesn't really count as anything “proper” at the higher level? Such messages are great for “are you still there” messages, but require understanding the higher-level protocol; they're not at the TCP level.

Comment: @DonalFellows That's no different from TCP keepalive. It doesn't keep the connection alive, it just lets you detect the drop. That's not what he's asking for.

Comment: No, I meant exactly what I said. There is *nothing* you can do, and TCP keepalive won't do it. It continues to baffle me why useful content gets deleted here. 'So you mean', i.e. putting words into other people's mouths, is a bad habit. Lose it.

Answer (score 0):

> tried with setsockopt but it didn't worked as it is in C

There is currently no built-in way of setting at the script level the `SO_KEEPALIVE` on a socket controlled by Tcl as a Tcl channel (`fconfigure`). See also [TIP#344](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/tip/344.md).

Comment: Aside, as pointed out by others, the option might not help at all with what you are actually after. I sense an [`X-Y problem`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).